# Enity Framework ASP NET '@User.Identity.GetUserId() SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola tengo la siguiente cuestion, soy nuevo en **Entity Framework** y estoy usandolo para hacer un ERP, la cuestión es que ya tengo todo el registro de usarios y eso, pero me he llevado la sopresa de que cuando intetno llamar vía **Indentity** al supuesto **ID** de mi tabla, me llega algo distinto.
Esto es a lo que voy

esto :

```
  var idx = '@User.Identity.GetUserId()';
```

me duevle

> 20e9130f-c0e2-4245-ae86-27f66a7f4d30

Pero en BD mi id es

> ccbc7b1e-d8b3-4219-8bcb-2b9961f6c00a

Entonces cuando quiero hacer cosa como un simple select por id, pues me manda vacio, alguein sabe a que se podría deber? o como puedo llamar a mi ID de la base de datos, hasta donde tengo entendido, todos los datos se llaman de ahí, no tengo el mismo problema como en el **EMail** por ejemplo.

Mis cadenas de conexion son:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
     <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBEnt" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model1.csdl|res://*/Data.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=DemoFSWebApp;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: ¿Has visto la tabla donde guardas al usuario? ¿Es la misma que genera ASP net Identity?

Comment: Pues hasta donde tengo entendido, si. ¿Cómo corroboro que es la misma? , quiero pensar que si porque puedo llamar al mail y al username y toma los valores de la tabla que creo

Comment: En la db solo tienes un unico usuario ? no puede generarse el caso que ese id sea de un usuario diferente

Comment: @fredyfx hola mi querido mentor, oye fijate que trate de hacer el cambio tal como sugieres, incluso eliminé el usuario que estaba en mi bd, pero resulta que el usuario persiste aunque no esté en la base de datos, no obstante cuando hice el registro de usuario, se insertó directamente allí en la misma tabla de donde lo borré, si le cambio la string connection no me deja registrar y hacer otras cosas

Comment: gracias por el halago hermano, verifica si hay algo en LocalDB. También vas a tener que revisar todas las cadenas de conexión que tengas

Comment: @fredyfx si, es que tu siempre contestas mis code de spaguetti, voy a subir las cadenas a ver si vez algo

Comment: @fredyfx oye o sabes como puedo ver la lista de estos "usuarios" que se están registrando?

Comment: En la tabla de AspNetUsers

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu clase `IdentityModels.cs`:

Reemplaza:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
```

Por:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyConnectionString") { }
```

El motivo:

Por defecto, la información de las tablas generadas por ASPnet Identity se almacena en un LocalBD, a pesar que ya definiste en tu `web.config` la cadena correcta y todo el tema, es importante verificar hacia dónde está apuntando el `ApplicationDbContext` en cuanto a cadena de conexión se refiere.

Respuesta basada en: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873607/3613462